# Updating image in VB and SQL Server not working

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

```
Private Sub UpdateBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateBTN.Click
    Dim IDdelete = Me.DataGridView1.Item(0, Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Value
    da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Spic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName)

    da.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand
    da.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "update Students set Fname = ' " & FnameTXT.Text & "' , Lname = ' " & LnameTXT.Text & "' , DOB = ' " & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "' , Address = '" & AddressTXT.Text & "' , Nationality = '" & NationalityCBX.Text & "' , Img =  '@Spic'  where StudentID = '" & IDdelete & "'"
    da.UpdateCommand.Connection = con

    con.Open()
    da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Before anything, fix your huge security flaw; your code is wide open to Injection

Comment: A title and some code is NEVER a good question. You ALWAYS need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, exactly what you're doing and exactly what happens when you do it.

Comment: You should not be using the `image` data type in SQL Server. The documentation has stated clearly that it is deprecated for over a decade now, so there's no excuse. For any binary data, including that for images, should be stored in a `varbinary` column.

Comment: You obviously know, in general terms, how to use parameters in ADO.NET so do it. Don't do it just for binary data but for ALL data. Assume that it is NEVER safe to not use parameters to save user-entered data. Data that comes from the application can be, e.g. values selected from drop-down lists, but there's really no reason not to use parameters for ALL variable data. If you do it for all then you can't accidentally not do it when you should.

Answer (score 1):

There are other things wrong with that code but I'll concentrate on the two that most directly pertain to your stated issue.

Firstly, you have this within your SQL code:

```sql
Img =  '@Spic'
```

That is wrong.  If you want to use the value of a variable in VB, would you wrap the name of the variable in double-quotes? Of course you wouldn't! That would use a `String` containing the name of the variable rather than the value of the variable itself. With that in mind, why would you wrap the name of a SQL parameter in single-quotes when the purpose of single-quotes in SQL is specifically to denote a literal string?

Even if you fix that though, it's still not going to work because of this:

```vb
da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Spic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName)

da.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand
```

You add a parameter to the command object that is currently assigned to the `UpdateCommand` property, then you immediately discard that command object and replace it with a new one. If you have a bowl of ice cream and you put chocolate sprinkles on it, then toss the ice cream and put a new scopp in the bowl, would you be surprised that there are no chocolate sprinkles on it? Of course not. That's exactly what you would expect, so why would you think that it would be any different here?